# Loading more items on the listView instead of n+2 items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a **ListView** on my android application , in each list item I have a **ViewPager** that contains some images , The images are downloading from web.

The performance of listView is not perfect and on scroll when listView wants to show next row app is freezing for about **0.3 second** . I tried **volley** for downloading images also I tried downloading image using **async tasks** but still app has the same issue.

So I tried to find another applications that used listView with ViewPager to show images slider inside list view items , I see that this applications are loading more rows on the list view so when I scroll the rows are ready to show and application is working normal , But if I scroll so fast their application has the same issue as my application.

SO my question is : "How I should change default number of items that load on a list view (number of items that shows on screen + 2) ? ".

Also Please let me know if you know any other solution to improve my list view performance.

Answer (score 1):

For image loading in listviews I suggest you try Picasso Library

[Get it here](https://github.com/square/picasso)

if the performance doesn't improve its best if you provide your adapter code

Comment: Thanks , This library helped to improve the performance and now scrolling is more smooth but still is not normal like other applications , Any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

the best way to have loads of images and get a smoother scroll is to use Picasso with a scroll listener.

create a TAG object somewhere:

```
public static final Object PICASSO_TAG = new Object();
```

to load images you call:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```

then on `AbsListView.OnScrollListener`

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
  if(SCROLL_STATE_IDLE == scrollState){
      Picasso.with(context).resumeTag(PICASSO_TAG);
  } else {
      Picasso.with(context).pauseTag(PICASSO_TAG);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , It helped to improve the performance , But without the listener that you shared the performance is better, Just using Picaso helped me , But still the listView scrolling is not smooth while images are not loaded , After all images loaded list scroll is smoother.

Comment: Hi if the performance is bad you may be doing stuff in the adapter not efficiently enough. For example...it hepls to set fonts/colors only when the cell is null, not after you have loaded the cell from the tag.